# tmux cuts symbols in status bar

Tags: bash, battery, tmux

For some reason, I can't use tmux battery plugin, so I've written a small script to get battery status:

```
percentage=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity)
status=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)
str=""
[ "$status" == "Charging" ] && str="^"
str="$str$percentage%"
echo $str
```

This script works fine in bash, printing something like '^78%'. Then I've included it in a statusbar:

```
set -g status-fg colour6
set -g status-attr bold
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right "%d/%m %H:%M:%S | #(~/.status/battery.sh) "
```

However, only '78%' is shown in statusbar, without '^' symbol indicating charging. I tried to print something like '78% (CHRG)', but again, only '78%' is displayed in statusbar, while bash runs script correctly.

I'm running tmux 2.6 and bash 4.4.18.

Comment: Could it be you have some old script elsewhere? If your config used to point to another script and you *didn't* restart your tmux server after you switched to a script with another path, the new configuration is not used. Exit all your `tmux` sessions and start over; or maybe just reload the proper file, e.g. `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: @kamil-maciorowski thanks for response. I tried to restart tmux server, or even to reboot my PC, but displayed message keeps the same.